# 3D Numpy arrays into ITK SNAP

Tags: numpy, itk

How to convert 3D Numpy arrays, which represent video of medical data to a proper file format that is compatible for ITK-SNAP application to do manual segmentation?

Answer (score 0):

[PyBuffer](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1PyBuffer.html) should be the class of choice for that conversion. It is part of Module_BridgeNumPy which needs to be enabled in CMake configuration step of ITK. If you want to use SimpleITK, [this](http://insightsoftwareconsortium.github.io/SimpleITK-Notebooks/01_Image_Basics.html) should help. Once you have a normal itk::Image, you can write it to disk using one of many supported [formats](https://itk.org/Wiki/ITK/File_Formats).

Answer (score -1):

You can import the 3d numpy array in Paraview.
Then export it as a NIH, nifti or analyze file which is compatible with ITKSnap

[image: paraview]

1. Save the 3d array to vtr file. You can follow the instructions of this link.
   https://www.kaggle.com/ironbar/saving...
2. Open the file with Paraview
3. Apply different thresholds to the data, depending on the problem the number and range will be different.
4. Apply different color and opacity to the thresholds
5. Visualize

After you get the correct file format you can load it in ITKSnap